# Should the variables of the (initial) state of a dynamic rnn among the inputs of a batch be shared?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is a tutorial for variable length sequences and RNN for Tensorflow:
https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html

Inside you see this:

```
init_state = tf.get_variable('init_state', [1, state_size],
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
init_state = tf.tile(init_state, [batch_size, 1])
```

What are the benefits (unless it is completely wrong) to do this instead ?:

```
init_state = tf.get_variable('init_state', [batch_size, state_size],
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
```

*Correct me if I am wrong but I think using `tile` above is chosen in order to share the variable instead of having a different variable for each part of the batch*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `tf.tile` will replicate the variable as described in the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile)

> This operation creates a new tensor by replicating input multiples times. The output tensor's i'th dimension has input.dims(i) * multiples[i] elements, and the values of input are replicated multiples[i] times along the 'i'th dimension. For example, tiling [a b c d] by [2] produces [a b c d a b c d].

This is also illustrated by the `_tile_grad` method which allows to aggregate the gradients of the tiled tensor (see the `gen_array_ops.py`file):

```
def _tile_grad(input, multiples, name=None):
  """Returns the gradient of `Tile`.

  Since `Tile` takes an input and repeats the input `multiples` times
  along each dimension, `TileGrad` takes in `multiples` and aggregates
  each repeated tile of `input` into `output`.
  ...
  """
```

If you don't tile the `init_state`, you would get as many initial states as the batch size and each of them would evolve differently as you train the method (as different gradients would be applied to them).